# Data alignment of structure using malloc

Tags: c, malloc, memory-alignment

Consider I have structure as below.

```
struct st
{
  char c;
  double d;
  int i;
};
```

As per memory alignment size of `struct st` will be (1+7(padded)+8+4+4(padded))=24bytes

When I do `malloc` as below

```
struct st *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
```

it will be same as

```
struct st *p = malloc(13);
```

How does malloc allocates 24 bytes to meet memory alignment since we are just passing the size of structure(13bytes)?

Comment: Can you show that `malloc(13)` does allocate 24 bytes?

Comment: It doesn't, it only allocates `13` bytes, but some systems allocate more than you asked for because they deal with memory in minimum sized chunks. Don't rely on this.

Comment: The alignment will depend on the implementation. For example, on 32-bit architectures it is likely that `double` only requires 4 byte alignment, in which case your `sizeof` is incorrect.

Comment: @WeatherVane In which case doing malloc is wrong for structure since it does not handle memory allignment?

Comment: @KBlr on my system `sizeof(struct st)` is `24` and consequently `sizeof(*p)`, so I don't know why you would even `malloc(13)` since you already know that `24` bytes are needed.

Comment: @Fredrik What part of my comment would indicate otherwise? (BTW you're also wrong in general, since c does not mandate ieee754 floating point, but that's neither here nor there).

Comment: @KBlr are you saying that `malloc` returns the same pointer value? I don't think there is any way to establish reliably exactly how much memory `malloc` reserved. If `malloc` returns a non-`NULL` value, you know it is successful and that is all you get to know. You could allocate memory for several `struct`s and compare the pointers returned, but `malloc` does not necessarily place each allocation consecutively.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you! Now I understand that padding happens at the compile time and sizeof returns 24 instead of 13 bytes

Comment: @WeatherVane In which case does malloc need to handle memory alignment since everything is handled by compiler?

Comment: The sizes and `struct` member alignment are handled at compile time. The actual allocation is handled at run time. Please see comments under these answers.

Comment: `malloc` aligns memory suitable for any object type.  If you want a different alignment then use `alligned_malloc()` - but in this case it is not necessary - that is typically only necessary for example to match an MMU page, SSE, cache line, or VM page boundary alignment.  24 byte alignment is not necessary to allocate this structure.

Comment: What makes you believe they are the same? They are not.  Show your evidence; it is not enough to just say they are the same.

Comment: @Clifford: How do you figure `malloc` aligns memory suitable for any object type? C 2018 7.20.3 says the pointer is suitably aligned that it may be assigned to any type of object with a fundamental alignment requirement. But if the C implementation does not care about pointer alignment during conversions and assignment, only during use, then any address satisfies that, so that part of 7.20.3 imposes no alignment requirement in such an implementation…

Comment: … It goes on to say the pointer may be used to access an object (or array) that fits, and that requirement means it must be aligned suitably for objects that fit—but not necessarily for larger objects.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I don&#39;t think your finding excludes my assertion. I deliberately summarised the behaviour rather than repeat the standard.  The point stands that it need not be a concern in this case, except in the sense that the allocation of 13 is too small, but that is a misunderstanding that has little to do with alignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question erroneously assumes that

```
struct st *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
```

is the same as

```
struct st *p = malloc(13);
```

It is not.   To test,

```
printf ("Size of st is %d\n", sizeof (*p));
```

which prints `24`, not 13.

The proper way to allocate and manage structures is with `sizeof(X)`, and not by assuming anything about how the elements are packed or aligned.

Comment: In this case there is nothing left for malloc to handle memory alignment and data packing, since everything will be handled by compiler

Comment: @KBlr: `malloc` does play a role in alignment. It is required to return memory suitably aligned for any supported object that might be placed in it. So, if you ask for 24 bytes, and the C implementation has objects less than or equal to 24 bytes in size that require 8-byte alignment, then the memory `malloc` returns must be at least 8-byte aligned. If you ask for 4 bytes, and the C implementation does not have any objects that size or smaller that require 8-byte alignment but does have 4-byte objects that require 4-byte alignment, then `malloc` only needs to return 4-byte-aligned memory.

Comment: @KBlr :  What memory alignment?  The only necessary alignment is the _start_ of the allocated block - the members are then aligned relative to that as determined by the padding applied by the compiler. `malloc()` is required ot return a pointer with suitable alignment for any object that will fit within the allocated space.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Using C11 and having included the appropriate header, I create the type (and type alias) `typedef struct {alignas(double) char ch;} Char;`. Obviously, `sizeof(Char) == sizeof(double)`. But is it UB to access the `ch` member of a `Char` in a memory allocation returned by `malloc(1)`?  I've always just assumed that `malloc` must conform to the same alignment regardless of its argument -- and, as far as I know, common implementations do -- but now you've got me wondering if it would really be legal for `malloc(1)` to return an unaligned pointer. TBH, the thought makes me nervous

Comment: @rici: `alignas` is not standard C. Supposing you use `_Alignas`, then you should not attempt to access a `Char` (or any part of it) through a pointer cast from the result of `malloc(1)`. A `Char` will be at least as large as the alignment requirement (not size) of a `double`, and, if that is greater than one, cannot be constructed in the space of `malloc(1)`. The wording for what alignment `malloc` must conform to in C 2018 7.22.3 is ambiguous to me, but the fact that a `Char` is (say) eight bytes means accessing it in a one-byte space is not proper.

Comment: @eric: `alignas` is standard if you `#include <stdalign.h>`. You might as well say that `malloc` is not standard since it also needs to be declared. That sort of hair-splitting is, imho, undignified and not conducive to a positive discussion.

Comment: But leaving that aside, what is your source for the claim that it is undefined to access a `char` from the beginning of a `Char`? We know that no padding may come before the `char` and I don't see anything that changes the size of the `char`. I'm not necessarily in disagreement with you, here. I'm just trying to arrive at a full understanding.

Comment: @rici: I said `alignas` was not standard because I missed it in the standard, not because I was making any distinction about including headers.

Comment: @rici: I did not write that it was undefined to access a `char` from the beginning of a `Char`. I wrote that it is not defined (by the C standard) to access ` char` from `Char` from a place where there cannot be a `Char`. If you have `Char *x; void *p; p = malloc(1); * (char *) p = 0; printf("%d\n", x->ch;`, then the `x->ch` is not proper C because it attempts to access a `Char` object from a place where no `Char` object exists.

Answer (score 0):

> *How does `malloc` allocate 24 bytes to meet memory alignment since we are just passing the size of structure (13 bytes)?*

It doesn't. If `malloc(13)` happens to return at least 24 bytes it's a quirk of the `malloc` implementation. `malloc` is allowed to allocate more space than necessary and often must for byte alignment and various other implementation reasons.

We can see this with a simple program.

```
struct st *a = malloc(13);
struct st *b = malloc(13);
struct st *c = malloc(13);
struct st *d = malloc(13);

printf("%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n", a, b, c, d);

0x602000003210
0x602000003230
0x602000003250
0x602000003270
```

As we can see from the addresses, the pointers returned by `malloc(13)` have 32 bytes between them. Plenty to fit your 24 bytes and the program "works". Even `malloc(1)` returns the same result.

But if we make your struct a little bigger...

```
struct st {
  char c;
  double b;
  double a;
  double d;
  int i;
};
```

That's 40 bytes, aligned. Now it doesn't fit into 32 bytes and we see corruption because the struct's memory overlap with each other.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct st {
  char c;
  double b;
  double a;
  double d;
  int i;
};

void print_struct(struct st* st) {
    printf("%c %lf %d\n", st->c, st->d, st->i);
}

int main() {
    const size_t struct_size = sizeof(char) + (sizeof(double) * 3) + sizeof(int);

    printf("sizeof(struct st): %zu\n", sizeof(struct st));
    printf("sizeof fields added together: %zu\n", struct_size);

    struct st *a = malloc(13);
    struct st *b = malloc(13);
    struct st *c = malloc(13);
    struct st *d = malloc(13);

    printf("%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n", a, b, c, d);

    a->c = 'a';
    a->d = 1.0;
    a->i = 1;

    b->c = 'b';
    b->d = 2.0;
    b->i = 2;

    c->c = 'c';
    c->d = 3.0;
    c->i = 3;

    d->c = 'd';
    d->d = 4.0;
    d->i = 4;

    print_struct(a);
    print_struct(b);
    print_struct(c);
    print_struct(d);
}

sizeof(struct st): 40
sizeof fields added together: 29
0x602000003210
0x602000003230
0x602000003250
0x602000003270
a 1.000000 98
b 2.000000 99
c 3.000000 100
d 4.000000 4
```

98 is ascii `b`. 99 is ascii `c`. 100 is ascii `d`. This indicates that `a->i` overlaps with `b->c`, `b->i` overlaps with `c->c`, and so on.

Comment: This answer accepts the question’s false premise that `sizeof *p` produces 13 and fails to correct it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil OIC, the OP thinks `sizeof(*p)` is 13. Well, it answers the other half of the question; why `malloc(13)` happens to work.